# Best Wordpress Plugin to integrate external API´s

Tags: wordpress

I´m looking for a Wordpress Plugin in order to retrieve data from external api´s and display this data in posts / on wordpress pages. I googled a lot, but haven´t found yet a plugin to do this. Can anyone recommend such a plugin? Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Some APIs will have a snippet code example on how to connect to their service & extract data. Then you can use those data & save them as posts. [PHP Guzzle library](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) is used by many open source projects for getting data from websites/APIs. Also, you need to read WordPress API on [how to insert new post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

Comment: There isn't going to be one plugin for this. APIs vary too much. Assuming the API is well-written, it shouldn't be too tough to create your own integration, especially if you aren't rate-limited and don't need to store the API responses in your database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually there will be no plugin available for API. It's totally depend on what type of API you are using. 
Many API provides the document tutorial which will clearly give, how to pull data, edit, display on the page etc. Also, you have not specified the API which you are using. We request you to please share the API link.
Meanwhile, you could give a try with the following example.

```
$url = "http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/audible-coffee.js?
api_key=API_KEY&callback=?";
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata);
```

Or

```
   $url="https:/zyz.com/GetJobPackage&jobidABRASIruWl;
   $content = file_get_contents($url);
   $array = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($content)),1);
   echo '<pre>';
   echo print_r($array);
```

Something like you can try it. 
Please share your API link, then we can or anyone can help you.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well I found myself in similar situation where I needed to connect to apis from my seller. Luckily I came through [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-api-for-wp/) on wp and its pro version got my job done.
Their support team helped me with the setup and walk through the plugin features.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32035317)